# what is the best way to learn islamic knowledge for myself

Tags: quran, hadith

how can i learn islamic knowledge for myself so i don’t have to ask many questions about islam, i want to learn about fasting, purity and prayer  if i learn about this it will be beneficial as i can answer questions and not ask too many questions, thanks in advance

Comment: Questions about best/worst etc. attract subjective answers and are therefore a bad fit for this site. You should learn this with a teacher not via websites nor books as both can't help you if you are stuck.

Comment: oh i’m sorry will keep in mind

Answer (score 1):

Assalam o allaikum.

There are a variety of sites where you may find various different stuff to enhance your knowledge about Islam. But personally, I would like to suggest you to, first of all, read the complete Quran in the language that you understand. You will surely get answers to many common things that we don't know or just misunderstand. After reading the Quran go for Hadiths.

After you have done with that, you can also go to any Mosque and discuss it with the Imam. Discussing on such topics physically helps you a lot than just reading on the internet.

Answer (score -1):

There are online sites teaching Islam

https://www.newmuslims.com/level/1

https://subjecteducator.com/islam-learning/

https://www.dar-alifta.org/Foreign/Articles.aspx?ID=2

(you can google it but some sites may be less recommendable).

Go to a mosque or islamic center. You will meet people there and practise. Don't be shy, do not hide that you are learning to practise.

Comment: oh i’m already a practicing muslim i just have loads of doubts and don’t wanna bother everyone with specific questions

Comment: Ok. I have been reading between lines so I thought you were learning to practice. But if you know the essentials, don't hesitate to ask. This site is made for that.